# How to perform arithmetic on java.sql.Time objects?

Tags: java, mysql, time

I have some java.sql.Time objects as follows:

```
    String s1 = "12:00:04";
    String s2 = "12:23:34";
    String s3 = "12:03:02";
    String s4 = "11:00:54";

    int dij = j-i;
    int dmj = j-m;
    java.sql.Time tdi = java.sql.Time.valueOf(s1);
    java.sql.Time tki = java.sql.Time.valueOf(s2);
    java.sql.Time tdm = java.sql.Time.valueOf(s3);
    java.sql.Time tdj = java.sql.Time.valueOf(s4);
```

How can I perform subtract operations of these objects? I want to get the result in java.sql.Time object itself but number of seconds will work too.
Most of the methods given in java.sql.Time class are deprecated. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html

Comment: Arithmetic is much simpler using the [Calendar Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `java.sql.Time` wraps a `java.util.Date`, I'm not sure that subtraction and putting the result in a `java.sql.Time` object is *meaningful*.

I would rather perform the subtraction (most likely using the milliseconds field and the [getTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) accessor), and store the result as a numeric representing the number of seconds/milliseconds etc.

If you're performing a lot of arithmetic, the solution is most likely to look at [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). See the FAQ for [arithmetic-related](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html#datediff) info. Joda-Time has a more consistent and useful API, plus is thread-safe (unlike the standard `java.util.Date/Calendar`)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you tu use the [Joda Time java library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) which is very good at handling dates and times in Java.

example:

```
public boolean isRentalOverdue(DateTime datetimeRented) {
  Period rentalPeriod = new Period().withDays(2).withHours(12);
  return datetimeRented.plus(rentalPeriod).isBeforeNow();
}
```